# Deploy multiple Web Site to one Azure service

Tags: asp.net, cloud, azure-cloud-services

I am new to windows azure. I have requirement that I have to achieve. I have searched on the google but it was not useful.
I have to deploy multiple web sites to 1 cloud service. Is there any possibility?  I will make them ssl enabled with multiple certificates in one cloud service.

So url's will be like:
https:// mysite/Home/

https:// mysite2/Home/

https:// mysite3/Home/

Actually my requirement is I should be able to deploy multiple web site and able to change the web.config after deployment. I think this we can do by enabling remote machine to the cloud service. After that we can login to remote machine and change the web.config file through iis manager. Am I correct?

Do we have any best way to achieve the requirement? I have to consider the minimum cost for this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using Web Apps instead? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/ You can add multiple Web Apps to the same shared instance tier.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have only one web site in my solution but i have to deploy it with 3 urls... Do you think it would be possible? I assume it will be having 3 web.config for each web site. I would like to update this after deployment.

Comment: It's not clear if you need to deploy 1 site/app or 3 (is the code responding to all 3 URLs the same or different?). You can have as many URLs as you like pointing to the same website, that's a DNS configuration and has nothing to do with the technology you use to deploy your site. Also, it's not a good thing to modify a file through RDP, as you never know when the VM running your code is replaced by another one, and this new one will NOT have the modified file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.Actually It is only one web site...But i would like three 3 Urls with each having it's own web.config.  Can we deploy the same site as three web roles.. ? this is clients requirement. They want this way only.

Comment: Yes, you can deploy the same project in multiple web roles so they have an independent configuration (in the same cloud service or a different one for each). Also, you should consider putting the configuration that will change in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file, not in the web.config. This way you can change the configuration without redeploying the roles.

Comment: It shows me below message. I think we can't deploy multiple role to same azure service. it shows me below Message.                                                         "the Selected deployment environment is in use, would you like to replace the current deployment".   I am using staging environment for the deployment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89067/discussion-between-gbellmann-and-user3463768).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but it shows how to run multiple websites in the same web role: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/

Regarding the changes in the web.config, you should not do that, because your instances may be changed, and those new instances will not have the modified file. All the configuration you are willing to change after deployment should be stored in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file. This way you can modify the configuration without redeploying, and the configuration is shared among all instances of the service.